# Lua automated tests with JUnit-style xml output?

Tags: xml, testing, junit, lua

I'm looking for something to generate junit style xml for automated tests of lua code -- lunit and luaunit are two sparesly maintained testing frameworks, but I haven't been able to find a junit frontend for them. I'd rather (obviously) use someone else's proven code then roll my own, but a testing framework for lua that allows for easy customization of the output would also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method which uses Luaunit and Genx to output jUnit compatible XML for Jenkins:

http://blog.gbanga.com/2011/05/lua-unit-test-results-in-jenkins/